# Automated call of values by name

Tags: r

I have a list Frequencies which consists of data with names for each value.  The names are a combination of a locus name (before the decimal) and an allele number (behind the decimal). I am trying to do a series of calculations such as the following:

```
expD12 <- (1-((Freqs[["D12S391.14"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.15"]])^2+ (Freqs[["D12S391.16"]])^2+
(Freqs[["D12S391.17"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.17.1"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.17.3"]])^2+
(Freqs[["D12S391.18"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.18.1"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.18.3"]])^2+
(Freqs[["D12S391.19"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.19.1"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.19.3"]])^2+
(Freqs[["D12S391.20"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.20.1"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.20.3"]])^2+
(Freqs[["D12S391.21"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.22"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.22.2"]])^2+
(Freqs[["D12S391.23"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.24"]])^2+(Freqs[["D12S391.24.3"]])^2))
```

While this code does what I need it to do, is there a cleaner way to do this perhaps involving a for loop and calling each value by name until it reaches a name before the decimal which is different?  I am asking this because I have to perform the same calculation for multiple loci for multiple datasets.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Do you want to use all alleles for a certain locus name?

Comment: Sorry about that.  The data used for this calculation is as follows:           
D12S391.19        D12S391.19.1        D12S391.19.3    D12S391.20 
0.1515444015      0.0033783784        0.0048262548    0.1264478764 
D12S391.20.1      D12S391.20.3        D12S391.21      D12S391.22 
0.0009652510      0.0004826255        0.1008687259    0.0661196911 
D12S391.22.2      D12S391.23          D12S391.24      D12S391.24.3 
0.0004826255      0.0492277992        0.0255791506    0.0004826255 
D12S391.25        D12S391.26          D12S391.27         
0.0115830116      0.0033783784        0.0024131274

Comment: And yes, I do need to use all alleles for a certain locus name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been better if you had included a reproducible example; here's a shot at that:

```
Freqs = list(D12S391.14=.1, D12S391.15=.2, D12S392.14=.3, D12S392.15=.4)
```

You can get all the locus names with something like:

```
locuses = unique(unlist(lapply(strsplit(names(Freqs), ".", fixed=TRUE),
                               function(x) x[1])))
```

Then you can use a function like the one listed by Sven to compute the value you want for each locus name:

```
sapply(locuses, function(x) 1 - sum(unlist(Freqs[grepl(x, names(Freqs))])^2))
# D12S391 D12S392 
#    0.95    0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
locus_name <- "D12S391"
1 - sum(unlist(Freqs[grepl(locus_name, names(Freqs))])^2)
```

This calculation will include all alleles for a certain `locus_name` .